# Setting the first item as selected item in WPF Combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am trying to set the first item in the combobox as the selected item by default. But the following code is not working:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="cbxPrograms" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="270" Height="28" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          SelectedIndex="0"              
          ItemsSource= "{Binding Path=ProgramCodeSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding ProgramCode, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Comment: shouldn't your binding in SelectedItem be ProgramCodeSource not ProgramCode?

Comment: have a look at this page http://timhibbard.com/blog/2012/04/17/wpf-combobox-initial-selection/

Comment: Probably a silly question but you are setting ProgramCode to be the first object in the ProgramCodeSource collection before the binding, or raising a property change if set after the binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a collection property named `ProgramCodeSource` and a property named `ProgramCode` of the same type as the items in the collection...:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProgramCodeSource}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding ProgramCode, Mode=TwoWay}" ... />
```

... then you can select the first item in the `ComboBox` from the class that has the properties simply using `LinQ` like this:

```
ProgramCode = ProgramCodeSource.FirstOrDefault();
```

You could do it after you initialise your data:

```
ProgramCodeSource = new ObservableCollection<YourDataType>(GetData());
ProgramCode = ProgramCodeSource.FirstOrDefault();
```

It is good using the `FirstOrDefault` method because if the `GetData()` method returns nothing, there will be no error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your view-model looks like, but your SelectedItem needs to be set to an instance of the types in the list.

```
<ComboBox 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    x:Name="cbxPrograms" 
    Grid.Column="2" 
    Grid.Row="1"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="270" 
    Height="28" 
    SelectedIndex="0" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    ItemsSource= "
        {Binding Path=EntityCollectionSource, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
        NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Entity,Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Answer (score 0):

try use SelectedValue="{Binding ProgramCode, Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: I tried using selected value, but the first item is not selected by default.